# Al imprimir me sale un cuadrado en vez de el valor

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un codigo para completar triangulos, sus angulos, su area, etc. pero a la hora de imprimir los valores en el triangulo isosceles despues del switch es decir en la parte de:

```
 else if (ladoa == ladob || ladob == ladoc || ladoa == ladoc) {

if (ladoa==ladob){
```

en esa parte los valores se ingresan como un cuadrado y no como un valor, no se que realize mal o que me hace falta agregar para que el numero se imprima adecuadamente

añado codigo:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese los valores de cada lado y de la altura para calcular el area");
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor del lado a");
        double ladoa = entrada.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor del lado b");
        double ladob = entrada.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor del lado c");
        double ladoc = entrada.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de la altura");
        double altura = entrada.nextFloat();
        
        double valora=0;
        double acosenoA=0;
        double gradosA=0;
        double angulob=0;
        double anguloc=0;
        
        double areaequilatero =(ladoc*altura)/2;
        
        double perimetro=ladoa+ladob+ladoc;
        double semiperimetro=perimetro/2;
        double areaisoscelesyescaleno;
        areaisoscelesyescaleno =Math.sqrt(semiperimetro*(semiperimetro-ladoa)*(semiperimetro-ladob)*(semiperimetro-ladoc));
        

        DecimalFormat formato= new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
        
        double gradosb=0;
        
        if(ladoa == ladob && ladob == ladoc && ladoa == ladoc) {
            System.out.println("El triangulo es equilatero");
            areaequilatero = (ladoc*altura)/2;
            System.out.println("El triangulo tiene un area de" + formato.format(areaequilatero)+"cm2");
        } else if (ladoa != ladob && ladob != ladoc && ladoa!=ladoc){
            System.out.println("El triangulo es escaleno");
            perimetro=ladoa+ladob+ladoc;
            semiperimetro=perimetro/2;
            areaisoscelesyescaleno =Math.sqrt(semiperimetro*(semiperimetro-ladoa)*(semiperimetro-ladob)*(semiperimetro-ladoc));
            System.out.println("El triangulo tiene un area de" + formato.format(areaisoscelesyescaleno)+"cm2");
        } else if (ladoa == ladob || ladob == ladoc || ladoa == ladoc) {
            System.out.println("El triangulo es isosceles");
            perimetro=ladoa+ladob+ladoc;
            semiperimetro=perimetro/2;
            areaisoscelesyescaleno =Math.sqrt(semiperimetro*(semiperimetro-ladoa)*(semiperimetro-ladob)*(semiperimetro-ladoc));
            System.out.println("El triangulo tiene un area de" + formato.format(areaisoscelesyescaleno)+"cm2");
        }
        
        valora = (Math.pow(ladoa, 2) - Math.pow(ladob, 2) - Math.pow(ladoc, 2))/-(2*ladob*ladoc);
        acosenoA=Math.acos(valora);
        gradosA= Math.toDegrees(acosenoA);
        
        System.out.println("Con el numero 1 revisamos el valor de los angulos y con el numero 2 cierras el sistema");
       int opcion = entrada.nextInt();
        
        switch(opcion) {
        
            case 1:
            if(ladoa == ladob && ladob == ladoc && ladoa == ladoc){
                System.out.println("El triangulo equilatero siempre tiene 60° en cada uno de sus angulos, pues es un triangulo rectangulo");           
            }else if(ladoa != ladob && ladob != ladoc && ladoa != ladoc){
                valora = (Math.pow(ladoa, 2) - Math.pow(ladob, 2) - Math.pow(ladoc, 2));
                acosenoA = Math.acos(valora);
                gradosA= Math.toDegrees(acosenoA);
                
                
                double senoA = Math.sin(gradosA);
                angulob= (ladob*senoA)/ladoa;
                double acosenoB= Math.acos(angulob);
                gradosb= Math.toDegrees(acosenoB);
                
                senoA= Math.sin(gradosc);
                anguloc= (ladoc*senoA)/ladoc;
                double acosenoC = Math.acos(anguloc);
                double gradosc= Math.toDegrees(acosenoC);
                
                System.out.println("el triangulo escaleno tiene su angulo A "+ formato.format(gradosA) +"°, su angulo B "+formato.format(gradosb)+"° y su angulo C"+formato.format(gradosc)+"°");
                
            }else if (ladoa == ladob || ladob == ladoc || ladoa == ladoc){
                if (ladoa==ladob){
                    valora = (Math.pow(ladoa, 2) - Math.pow(ladob, 2) - Math.pow(ladoc, 2));
                    acosenoA = Math.acos(valora);
                    gradosA= Math.toDegrees(acosenoA);
                    
                    System.out.println("El triangulo isosceles tiene su angulo A "+ formato.format(gradosA) +"°");
                    
                    gradosb=gradosA;
                    
                    gradosc=(180-gradosA-gradosb);
                            
                }
            }
             
        }
```

Comment: Pues hice un debug y tus valores llegan bien https://ibb.co/2SW4w36. La lógica es la que no tiene sentido: ¿valorA = a² - b² - c² para un isosceles? ¿Qué fórmula es esa?

Comment: ya revise la logica, perdon, pero aun asi, a la hora de imprimir hay fallas, https://ibb.co/j6R47Lg. ¿Que hice mal?

Answer (score 1):

Para hallar el angulo A,B y C debes usar la ley de cosenos ya que conoces los lados del triangulo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aplicado en java

[Math.acos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#acos-double-)             -> devuelve en radianes

[Math.toDegrees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees-double-)      -> convierte en sexagesimal

[Math.round](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-)(dato*100)/100d;-> devulve el valor en formato #.00

```
double anguloA=Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(((Math.pow(b,2))+(Math.pow(c,2))-(Math.pow(a,2)))/(2*b*c)))*100)/100d;
double anguloB=reemplaza valores en la formula anterior
double anguloC=180-(anguloA+anguloC);
```

observacion:
si ya declaraste las formulas en el punto 1 no es necesario volver a declararlas en el punto 2 solo coloca el nombre de la variables ;)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]